# "Negating" a String gives unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was playing around with `String` and its constructor and noticed some behaviour I can't explain.

I created the following method

```java
public static String negate(String s) {
    byte[] b = s.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = (byte)(~b[i] + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    return new String(b);
}
```

which simply does a 2's complement on each `byte` and returns a new `String` for that. When calling it like

```java
System.out.println(negate("Hello"));
```

I got an output of

```java
[-72, -101, -108, -108, -111]
�����
```

which I guess is fine, since there are no negative ASCII values.
But when I nested the calls like so

```java
System.out.println(negate(negate("Hello")));
```

my output was like this

```java
[-72, -101, -108, -108, -111]
[17, 65, 67, 17, 65, 67, 17, 65, 67, 17, 65, 67, 17, 65, 67]
ACACACACAC // 5 groups of 3 characters (1 ctrl-char and "AC")
```

I expected the output to match exactly my input string `"Hello"`, but instead I got this. Why? This also happens with every other input string. After nesting, each single character from the input becomes just `AC`.

I went farther and created a method that does the same thing, but only with raw `byte` arrays

```java
public static byte[] n(byte[] b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = (byte)(~b[i] + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    return b;
}
```

Here the output is as expected. For

```java
System.out.println(new String(n(n("Hello".getBytes()))));
```

I get

```java
[-72, -101, -108, -108, -111]
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
Hello
```

So I guess it has to do with the way `String`s are created, since it only happened when I called `negate` with an instance that already got the negative `byte`s?

I even walked down the class tree to look at the internal classes but I couldn't find where this behaviour comes from.

Also in the docs of [String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28byte%5B%5D%29) there's following paragraph which might be an explanation:

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified

Can anybody tell me why it's like this and what exactly is happening here?

Comment: Um, yes - you're trying to interpret arbitrary bytes which aren't actually encoded text as if they're encoded text. I would strongly suggest you don't do that.

Comment: If you use a charset that maps 256 bytes (like ISO-8859-1 for example), it works with the first method

Comment: And, nothing you are doing involves ASCII. [String.getBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) could be made to but its purpose is very specific: To vary according to the computer's operating system's user's current settings. Not useful in any domain that I've worked in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you're taking the inverted bytes and trying to interpret them as a valid byte stream in the default character set (remember, characters are not bytes). So as the string constructor docs you quoted tell you, the result is unspecified, and probably involves error-correction, dropping invalid values, etc., etc. Naturally, then, it's a lossy process, and reversing it will not get you back your original string.

If you get the bytes and double-negate them **without** converting the intermediate bytes to string, you'll get back your original result.

This example demonstrates the lossy nature of `new String(/*invalid bytes*/)`:

```
String s = "Hello";
byte[] b = s.getBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    b[i] = (byte)(~b[i] + 1);
}
// Show the negated bytes
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
String s2 = new String(b);
// Show the bytes of the string constructed from them; note they're not the same
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s2.getBytes()));
```

On my system, which I believe defaults to UTF-8, I get:

```
[-72, -101, -108, -108, -111]
[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67]
```

Note what happened when I took the invalid byte stream, made a string out of it, and then got the bytes of that string.

Answer (score 2):

You "negate" a character and it becomes invalid. Then you get the placeholder `�` (U+FFFD). At this point everything is corrupted. Then you "negate" that, and you get your `AC` from each of the placeholder chars.

Comment: Well, it depends. UTF-8 isn't the default charset everywhere.

Comment: Well no, but it's the case here and I don't want to stretch this out to a "how does encoding work" answer.